# How can a SafeHandle be used in a P/Invoke signature that requires a null pointer in certain cases?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport, cer

Hopefully this isn't too obscure for SO, but consider the following P/Invoke signature:

```
[DllImport("odbc32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern OdbcResult SQLAllocHandle(
    OdbcHandleType HandleType,
    IntPtr InputHandle,
    ref IntPtr OutputHandlePtr);
```

I'd like to redesign this signature to use SafeHandles, as follows:

```
[DllImport("odbc32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern OdbcResult SQLAllocHandle(
    OdbcHandleType HandleType,
    MySafeHandle InputHandle,
    ref MySafeHandle OutputHandlePtr);
```

However, [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms712455%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), the InputHandle argument must be a null pointer when the HandleType argument is SQL_HANDLE_ENV and a non-null pointer otherwise.

How do I capture those semantics in a single P/Invoke signature? Please include an example call-site in your answer. My current solution is to use two signatures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SafeHandle` is a class so you should be able to pass `null` rather than an actual `SafeHandle`.  A null reference is marshaled as a null pointer in P/Invoke.

```
SafeHandle handle = new SafeHandle();
OdbcResult result= SQLAllocHandle(OdbcHandleType.SQL_HANDLE_ENV, null, ref handle);
```

Comment: It is also possible to declare an `out SafeHandle` parameter.

Comment: Doesn't work here, I'm getting an `ArgumentNullException` from `System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(SafeHandle pHandle, Boolean& success)`.

Comment: Yes, @shf301, this doesn't work in P/Invoke calls. Did you even try it?

Answer (score 2):

[The answer by shf301](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8370067/27423) passes `null` for the input argument `InputHandle`. This doesn't work on most APIs (maybe it somehow does for the OP's specific problem, given that they accepted the answer).

I use this pattern:

```
[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, UnmanagedCode = true)]
public class RegionHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    private RegionHandle() : base(true) {}

    public static readonly RegionHandle Null = new RegionHandle();

    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
    override protected bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        return Region.DeleteObject(handle);
    }
}
```

It means I can do this to pass a null handle:

```
SomeApi(RegionHandle.Null);
```

It's similar to how there's an `IntPtr.Zero` static member.